# 11.04 ATI Radeon HD 5600 Dual Monitor issue

Tags: 11.04, xorg, ati, multiple-monitors

I have an issue when I try to work with dual monitor:

Ihave a HP dv7 with ati Radeon HD 5600 and a Benq external monitor.

I have instaled the properietary ATI drivers

When I plug my external monitor, the system freeze with balck screen with just the mouse pointer showed but freezed too. If I try to restart I can see the dual monitor working buit just mirrored, if I try to move to not mirrored monitors, the system freeze another time with black screen and the mouse pointer freezed.

The same issue I experiment even if I try, with my second monitor unplugged, to change the resolution of my laptop monitor

Any idea? please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have a VGA monitor at the left of my HDMI monitor. My HDMI monitor is my primary monitor. These commands were my solution:

    xrandr --output HDMI1 --scale 1.000x1.0001;
    xrandr --output VGA1 --scale 1.000x1.0001;
    xrandr --output VGA1 --left-of HDMI1;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.. Incredibly simple...

The solution was deleting the xorg.conf file and let the xserver to makes it's business without that and everything works!

Comment: This was not working for me.